# Liquibase causes "could not prepare statement; SQL" only with H2

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, h2, liquibase

I integrated Liquibase in my Spring Boot application. Using it with MariaDB works fine.

For unit & integration testing I use a H2 in-memory database. While running tests it causes following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select user0_.id as id1_19_0_, user0_.created_at as created_2_19_0_, user0_.updated_at as updated_3_19_0_, user0_.version as version4_19_0_, user0_.activated as activate5_19_0_, user0_.birthday as birthday6_19_0_, user0_.email as email7_19_0_, user0_.firstname as firstnam8_19_0_, user0_.force_password_change as force_pa9_19_0_, user0_.password_hash as passwor10_19_0_, user0_.role as role11_19_0_, user0_.surname as surname12_19_0_ from users user0_ where user0_.id=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
```

My prod config (working):

```yaml
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3307/testdb
    username: user
    password: psw

  jpa:
    generate-ddl: false
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect

  sql:
    init:
      mode: never

  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    change-log: classpath:db/db.changelog-master.yaml
```

My test config (not working):

```yaml
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;NON_KEYWORDS=user
    username: sa
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    password: password

  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    generate-ddl: false

  sql:
    init:
      mode: never

  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db/db.changelog-master.yaml
    enabled: true

  test:
    database:
      replace: none
```

What I tried:

- Multiple url configs including the `NON_KEYWORDS` option from H2 to exclude problems with user as it is maybe interpreted as a keyword.

As it is working with MariaDB I think it is a problem related to H2.

Thankful for any help, documentation, link whatever :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the problem was with my schema. As H2 does not support some features MariaDB does, it is not starting and therefore jpa is not able to prepare the SQL statement as the tables do not exist.